# Android show GPS position on "ground"

Tags: android, gps

I want to make a GPS application that shows a flat plain as ground and arrow (as user position) in the middle, while it should be possible to move along, the arrow should stay in the middle of screen and the ground should move. Also with a possibility of drawing on this "ground". 
Something like this:

[image: .]

I have GPS coordinates from external GPS through USB ports, so I would like to use them instead of phones GPS - I already have that one part. 
I am really stuck on how can I show the ground and move arround with drawing a path. I do not want to use google maps, because I dont need a map. Is something like this possible to do? I do not need 3D, a 2D would be OK as well.
Please, help me on showing the ground and moving arround with a location (or I can convert my location to carthesian coordinations).

Comment: A way to convert to cartesian coordinates should be easy to find in the web?

Comment: Yes, I know how to convert GPS to cartesian, that is not the problem. 
What I dont know is how to make "Ground" and how to automatically rotate it and draw path and lines on it based on coordinations (either GPS or Cartesian), maybe with zooming.